# PHP Built Multidimensional Array after explode function

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I try to found a function which build a multidimensional array after an explode.

For example :
Here I create array with as explode.

```
$str = 'root/foo/bar/file.jpg';
$ar = explode('/', $str);
```

$ar => array('root', 'foo' , 'bar', 'file.jpg');

Then I want this ouput :

```
array(3) {
  ['root']=>
       ['foo']=>
           ['bar']=> "file.jpg"
}
```

Any Idea ?

Thx

Comment: that's not how explode works. it takes a string and produces a SINGLE array with multiple entries representing the parts of whatever you exploded. it doesn't "go down" for you.

Comment: @MarcB is correct, once you explode the string you will wind up with single array and to make it multi-dimensional you will have to write your own function. If you would like the pursue that option though, we'd be more than happy to help you along the way.

Comment: I know how explode work, but I'm looking a function which converts a simple array in multidemensional array with each keys are previous array value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way that this problem can be approached.

```
<?php

$str = 'root/foo/bar/file.jpg';

$parts = explode("/", $str);
$leaf = array_pop($parts);
$tree = array();
$branch = &$tree;
foreach($parts as $v){
    $branch[$v] = array();
    $branch = &$branch[$v];
}
$branch = $leaf;

print_r($tree);
```

Try it yourself [here](http://3v4l.org/2MitV)

Comment: Really like your answer but I guess you made a little typo. `$branch[$v] = $leaf;` should be `$branch = $leaf;`

Comment: @PHPhil thanks caught and fixed it in the 3v4l link but not in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$str = 'root/foo/bar/file.jpg';
//Get last part of the filename
$parts = explode('/', $str);
$last = array_pop($parts);

$arr = [];
//Create code as string to fill in array
$codeParts = implode("']['", $parts);
$codeEx = "\$arr['{$codeParts}'] = \$last;";

eval($codeEx);

var_dump($arr);
```

https://eval.in/403480

Output:

```
array(1) {
  ["root"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["foo"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["bar"]=>
      string(8) "file.jpg"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While inventive using eval here is probably a bad idea

Comment: With this exact code, I don't see how it can be harmful. If the OP has no control over the strings being exploded or there's more info, then yes, it could cause problems. Could use a link on the dangers of eval.

Comment: How about not using eval for no other reason than you shouldn't need the extra overhead to assign an array element a value?

Comment: From Rasmus' own mouth `If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the
wrong question. -- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP`

Comment: @Orangepill I agree completely. But I didn't write the question.

Comment: @cspray - I'd love to see your solution :)